# Сравнение массивов

Tags: c++

Массивы разной длины и состоят из чисел. Нужно найти одинаковые элементы и вывести на экран.

Comment: Повторяющиеся одинаковые элементы печатать или нет ?

Answer (score 1):

```
f(int a[], int b[]) {
  print (intersect (a, b)) ;
}
```

Каков вопрос, таков ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку язык не известен то алгоритм такой :

```
Масив А \\Первый масив
Масив Б \\Второй масив
Масив В \\Массив в которм будут результат

числа :
i : счетчик для массива А
j : счетчик для массива Б
C : счетчик для массива В

c := 1;
for i= 1 to длина массива А do
begin
  for j = 1 to длинна массива Б do
  begin
    if A[i] = Б[j] then // сравниваем значения и если совпало то выполняем
    begin
      B[c] := A[c];
      c := c + 1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Ну а тут выводим масив В на экран.

Это смесь русского и Pascal ^)

Comment: А если одинаковых элементов больше одного? Скажем, две единицы в массиве A и пять в массиве Б? Сколько тогда единиц попадет в массив В? Также не указано как выделить память под массив В =)

Comment: одну цифру, думаю достаточно

Comment: кстати спасибо, думаю на паскале тоже пригодится)

Comment: Суть в том что когда я писал ответ, вопрос не стоял не по языку не по условиям.
Я просто написал один из вариантов решения задачи, на смеси русского и паскаля.

Comment: @gecube я не писал рабочий код, а показал только Вариант решения задачи. Если в А 2 поля 1 и в Б 5 полей 1 то в В будет 10 полей с 1.
Ни кто при  постановке задачи не ставил задачи уникальности.